# Xamarin Android webview

Tags: xamarin.android

Am new to xamarin Android.. I developed an app using webview to display my school site and it requires username and password .is there any way to remember username and password than typing everything againL

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and correct your question due to instruction.

Comment: you could use webview sets the cookie to remain logged in